# getting 404 when trying to access microsoft graph api endpoint https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-identity-platform

Hi I am trying to access the microsoft graph endpoint https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts but I receive a 404.

** ISSUES IT SHOULDN'T BE **

1. it should not be the problem with the exchange mailbox, since it works for the user in the explorer
2. it's not the code, since the token from the graph explorer works in the code
3. both tokens seems to have the same permissions

The image below is a picture of the decoded accesstoken, one is from the graph explorer and one is a token received from my own Oauth flow (auth code grant), they are trying to access the same users contacts.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To access the https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts, I think "Contacts.ReadWrite" permission is also required which is missing in the scopes of the above image. Can you please check the permissions here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-contacts?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions.
[image]

Hope this resolves the issue. If not please share Client request id and timestamp of the query.